# Out of memory issue on memoization in recursion

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to solve the LeetCode problem [746. Min Cost Climbing Stairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-cost-climbing-stairs/description/):

> You are given an integer array `cost` where `cost[i]` is the cost of `i`<sup>th</sup> step on a staircase. Once you pay the cost, you can either climb one or two steps.
>
> You can either start from the step with index `0`, or the step with index `1`.
>
> Return *the minimum cost to reach the top of the floor*.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: cost = [10,15,20]
> Output: 15
> ```
>
> Explanation: You will start at index 1.
>
> - Pay 15 and climb two steps to reach the top.
>
> The total cost is 15.
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: cost = [1,100,1,1,1,100,1,1,100,1]
> Output: 6
> ```
>
> Explanation: You will start at index 0.
>
> - Pay 1 and climb two steps to reach index 2.
> - Pay 1 and climb two steps to reach index 4.
> - Pay 1 and climb two steps to reach index 6.
> - Pay 1 and climb one step to reach index 7.
> - Pay 1 and climb two steps to reach index 9.
> - Pay 1 and climb one step to reach the top.
>
> The total cost is 6.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> ```
> 2 <= cost.length <= 1000
> 0 <= cost[i] <= 999
> ```

My code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} cost
 * @return {number}
 */    
var minCostClimbingStairs = function(A) {
    A.unshift(0)
    let maxSum = A.reduce(
        (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
        0
    );

    let cache = []
    for(let i=0; i<A.length+2; i++){
        maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, 1) + 1   
        let arr1 = new Array(maxSum) 
        arr1.fill("10000")
        cache.push(arr1)
    }

    function findMin(A, step=0, sum =0){
      if(step+1 == A.length || step+2 == A.length){
            let result1 = sum + A[step]
            return "" + result1
      }
      
      if(step> A.length-1){
            return "99999";
      }
      
      let result1, result2
      if(cache[step+1][sum+A[step]] != "10000"){
          result1 = cache[step+1][sum+A[step]]
      }
      else{
          result1 = findMin(A, step+1, sum+A[step])
          cache[step+1][sum+A[step]] = "" + result1
      }
      if(cache[step+2][sum+A[step]] != "10000"){
          result2 = cache[step+2][sum+A[step]]
      }
      else{
          result2 = findMin(A, step+2, sum+A[step])
          cache[step+2][sum+A[step]] = "" + result2
      }
      let result = Math.min(+result1, +result2)
      cache[step][sum] = ""+ result
      return cache[step][sum]  
    }
    return findMin(A)
};
```

I had this code on recursion as well but I got the error of maximum time out on larger-scale data.

So I used memoization, and now with memoization, I get this error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

on this data:

```
cost = [841,462,566,398,243,248,238,650,989,576,361,126,334,729,446,897,953,38,195,679,65,707,196,705,569,275,259,872,630,965,978,109,56,523,851,887,91,544,598,963,305,481,959,560,454,883,50,216,732,572,511,156,177,831,122,667,548,978,771,880,922,777,990,498,525,317,469,151,874,202,519,139,670,341,514,469,858,913,94,849,839,813,664,163,3,802,21,634,944,901,446,186,843,742,330,610,932,614,625,169,833,4,81,55,124,294,71,24,929,534,621,543,417,534,427,327,179,90,341,949,368,692,646,290,488,145,273,617,596,82,538,751,80,616,763,826,932,184,630,478,163,925,259,237,839,602,60,786,603,413,816,278,4,35,243,64,631,405,23,638,618,829,481,877,756,482,999,973,718,157,262,752,931,882,741,40,77,535,542,879,607,879,321,46,210,116,244,830,591,285,382,925,48,497,913,203,239,696,162,623,291,525,950,27,546,293,108,577,672,354,256,3,671,998,22,989,557,424,251,923,542,243,46,488,80,374,372,334,190,817,150,742,362,196,75,193,162,645,859,758,433,903,199,289,175,303,475,818,213,576,181,668,243,297,572,549,840,161,292,719,226,338,981,345,203,655,210,65,111,746,76,935,406,646,976,567,32,726,638,674,727,861,426,297,349,464,973,341,452,826,223,805,940,458,468,967,107,345,987,553,407,916,103,324,367,864,74,946,712,596,105,194,79,634,855,703,70,170,543,208,739,632,663,880,857,824,258,743,488,659,647,470,958,492,211,927,356,488,744,570,143,674,502,589,270,80,6,463,506,556,495,713,407,229,689,280,162,454,757,565,267,575,417,948,607,269,852,938,560,24,222,580,604,800,628,487,485,615,796,384,555,226,412,445,503,810,949,966,28,768,83,213,883,963,831,390,951,378,497,440,780,209,734,290,96,398,146,56,445,880,910,858,671,164,552,686,748,738,837,556,710,787,343,137,298,685,909,828,499,816,538,604,652,7,272,729,529,343,443,593,992,434,588,936,261,873,64,177,827,172,712,628,609,328,672,376,628,441,9,92,525,222,654,699,134,506,934,178,270,770,994,158,653,199,833,802,553,399,366,818,523,447,420,957,669,267,118,535,971,180,469,768,184,321,712,167,867,12,660,283,813,498,192,740,696,421,504,795,894,724,562,234,110,88,100,408,104,864,473,59,474,922,759,720,69,490,540,962,461,324,453,91,173,870,470,292,394,771,161,777,287,560,532,339,301,90,411,387,59,67,828,775,882,677,9,393,128,910,630,396,77,321,642,568,817,222,902,680,596,359,639,189,436,648,825,46,699,967,202,954,680,251,455,420,599,20,894,224,47,266,644,943,808,653,563,351,709,116,849,38,870,852,333,829,306,881,203,660,266,540,510,748,840,821,199,250,253,279,672,472,707,921,582,713,900,137,70,912,51,250,188,967,14,608,30,541,424,813,343,297,346,27,774,549,931,141,81,120,342,288,332,967,768,178,230,378,800,408,272,596,560,942,612,910,743,461,425,878,254,929,780,641,657,279,160,184,585,651,204,353,454,536,185,550,428,125,889,436,906,99,942,355,666,746,964,936,661,515,978,492,836,468,867,422,879,92,438,802,276,805,832,649,572,638,43,971,974,804,66,100,792,878,469,585,254,630,309,172,361,906,628,219,534,617,95,190,541,93,477,933,328,984,117,678,746,296,232,240,532,643,901,982,342,918,884,62,68,835,173,493,252,382,862,672,803,803,873,24,431,580,257,457,519,388,218,970,691,287,486,274,942,184,817,405,575,369,591,713,158,264,826,870,561,450,419,606,925,710,758,151,533,405,946,285,86,346,685,153,834,625,745,925,281,805,99,891,122,102,874,491,64,277,277,840,657,443,492,880,925,65,880,393,504,736,340,64,330,318,703,949,950,887,956,39,595,764,176,371,215,601,435,249,86,761,793,201,54,189,451,179,849,760,689,539,453,450,404,852,709,313,529,666,545,399,808,290,848,129,352,846,2,266,777,286,22,898,81,299,786,949,435,434,695,298,402,532,177,399,458,528,672,882,90,547,690,935,424,516,390,346,702,781,644,794,420,116,24,919,467,543,58,938,217,502,169,457,723,122,158,188,109,868,311,708,8,893,853,376,359,223,654,895,877,709,940,195,323,64,51,807,510,170,508,155,724,784,603,67,316,217,148,972,19,658,5,762,618,744,534,956,703,434,302,541,997,214,429,961,648,774,244,684,218,49,729,990,521,948,317,847,76,566,415,874,399,613,816,613,467,191]
```

I thought storing strings in the cache array might have an advantage over using integers, but still I am not able to get rid of this error.

This code is working fine for smaller data like in the two examples given in the above code challenge description.

In another atttempt, I changed that cache from array to object so that I don't have to occupy wasted space in the cache array:

```
var minCostClimbingStairs = function(A) {        
    A.unshift(0)
    let cache = {}
    // for(let i=0; i<A.length+2; i++){
    //     maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, 1) + 1   
    //     let arr1 = new Array(maxSum) 
    //     arr1.fill("10000")
    //     cache.push(arr1)
    // }

    function findMin(A, step=0, sum =0){
      if(step+1 == A.length || step+2 == A.length){
            let result1 = BigInt(sum + A[step])
            return result1
      }
      
      if(step> A.length-1){
            return "99999";
      }
      
      let result1, result2
      let newSum = BigInt(sum+A[step])
      let step1 = step+1
      let step2 = step+2
      let key1 = step1 + "-" + newSum 
      let key2 = step2 + "-" + newSum
      let key = step + "-" + sum
      
      if(cache[key] != undefined){
          return cache[key]
      }

      if(cache[key1] != undefined){
          result1 = cache[key1]
      }
      
      else{
          result1 = findMin(A, step+1, sum+A[step])
          cache[key1] = result1
      }
      if(cache[key2] !=  undefined){
          result2 = cache[key2]
      }
      else{
          result2 = findMin(A, step+2, sum+A[step])
          cache[key2] = result2
      }
      let result = result2>result1 ? result1 : result2
     
      cache[key] = result
      return cache[key]  
    }
    return findMin(A)
};
```

but still the same error persists!

I changed the cache to have only one key which is step and i am not getting correct answer

```
var minCostClimbingStairs = function(A) {
    
        A.unshift(0)
        let cache = {}
        // for(let i=0; i<A.length+2; i++){
        //     maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, 1) + 1   
        //     let arr1 = new Array(maxSum) 
        //     arr1.fill("10000")
        //     cache.push(arr1)
        // }
    
        function findMin(A, step=0, sum =0){
          if(step+1 == A.length || step+2 == A.length){
                let result1 = BigInt(sum) + BigInt(A[step])
                return result1
          }
          
          if(step> A.length-1){
                return "99999";
          }
          
          let result1, result2
          let newSum = BigInt(sum)+BigInt(A[step])
          let step1 = step+1
          let step2 = step+2
          let key1 = step1 
          let key2 = step2 
          let key = step 
          
          if(cache[key] != undefined){
              return cache[key]
          }

          if(cache[key1] != undefined){
              result1 = cache[key1]
          }

          else{
              result1 = findMin(A, step+1, newSum)
              cache[key1] = result1
          }
          if(cache[key2] !=  undefined){
              result2 = cache[key2]
          }
          else{
              result2 = findMin(A, step+2, newSum)
              cache[key2] = result2
          }
          let result = result2>result1 ? result1 : result2
         
          cache[key] = result
          return cache[key]  
        }
        return findMin(A)
    };

for test case of
```

TestCase 1:

```
[0,1,0,0]

Expected: 0
Returned: 1
```

TestCase 2:

```
[1,100,1,1,1,100,1,1,100,1]

Expected: 6
Returned: 207
```

Answer (score 2):

The memory your code needs for `cache` can be 1000x1000 strings, and there is the memory needed for recursion.

Your cache is not keyed correctly. What you want to cache is the *best* result that can be achieved from a given step onward. So the key of your cache should not be a combination of step and sum, but of step only.

Here is how your top-down approach could be changed to use a cache keyed by step only:

```
var minCostClimbingStairs = function(cost) {
    const cache = Array(cost.length).fill(1e10);
    cache.push(0, 0);

    function recur(i) {
        if (cache[i] === 1e10) cache[i] = cost[i] + Math.min(recur(i+1), recur(i+2));
        return cache[i];
    }

    return Math.min(recur(0), recur(1));
};
```

However, you can do this with *constant* space complexity only. Instead of performing a top-down algorithm, do a [bottom-up one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Computer_programming): start at the end of the input array and walk back. At each step you only need to know two results: the one for the step ahead, and the one for 2 steps ahead. It is easy to keep track of these two results as you walk *backwards* along the input array.

Here is how that looks (spoiler):

> `var minCostClimbingStairs = function(cost) {
>      let dp = [0, 0]; // Results for the next two positions
>      for (let i = cost.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Walk backward
>          dp = [cost[i] + Math.min(...dp), dp[0]];
>      }
>      return Math.min(...dp);
>  };`

Comment: thank you so much for your response !! I added another code at end of my question where i changed array by the object and I thought this will decrease the size of the cache needed but still the problem persists !!

Looking at this, do you still think this is because of memory space by cache? 

I will look about the top down approach as well ( i have never heard about it, i am new to data structure and algorithm). 

Thank you

Comment: Your approach is top-down. But your cache shouldn't need to use the *sum* as part of the key. The cache should reflect what the best sum is at a certain step, not at a certain step and sum. The sum is the best (minimal) *value* you want to know for a certain step, so the step (only) should be the key in your cache.

Comment: I tried with only one element as key in the cache but got wrong output so thought i need to put both step and sum as key !!! I have added code in the question ( at the end) where i do not get correct output !! Now i am so confused what should be put as key in cache !! :(

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided code that performs the top-down approach with a cache keyed by step only.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i realised my recursion was itself wrong and even after spending more than 4/5 hours, i could not solve it !! Your answer helped me learn !! I will practice more, thank you so much